# How I use a textbox with jquery datepicker with icon

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I want use jquery datepicker in my asp.net application but it don't work

in my Project is a Folder (images) with Calender.ico

here my code in master.master:

```
 <script>

        $(function () {
            $("#txtVon").datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImage: '/images/Calender.ico', 
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy"
            });
        });

       </script>
```

here my code in createuser.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtVon" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" ></asp:TextBox>
```

How I make wrong? I don't see the icon

Comment: try gif or jpg,png instead of .ico

Comment: move your code to createuser.aspx instead of master page and than try

Comment: do you want datepicker to be visible on icon click as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want datepicker to be visible on icon click as well?
Here is what I do:

```
<input id='invdate' name='invdate' type='text'/>
<span style='padding:5px'><img id='dpimage' alt="img" src='calendar2.gif'></span>

$(function() {
  $("#invdate").datepicker();
  $("#dpimage").click(function () {
    $("#invdate").datepicker("show")
  });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a3Jfq/)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the ID of your textbox. You write **txtVon**, but ASP.NET renders something different. So client side the ID is more likely to be something like **C001_txtVon**.

So it's better to give your textbox a CssClass like **cDatePicker** and use that in your jQuery selector.

Or make your ID selector a bit more fuzzy, like `$("input[id*='txtVon']").datepicker({});`

And as a last note; you'd best use a .png file instead of .ico, because i don't think that .ico is supported correctly by all browsers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

Comment: alternatively, reference the textbox like `$('#<%=txtVon.ClientID%>')`

Answer (score 1):

instead of this

```
'/images/Calender.ico
```

place a non.ico image i.e like eg: calender.gif..something like that